# unrecognized type in a function call

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to print into a file in C++ and for some reason I keep getting this weird error:

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier
>   'ofstream'

I included the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

This is my function:

```
void Date::PrintDate(ofstream& resultFile) const
{
    resultFile << m_day << "/" << m_month << "/" << m_year;
}
```

I am `using namespace std`.

---

I figured it out, it was all because I did not include the file in the right way.

Comment: if the namespace is not your problem, please post a complete example (file) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: the file is an empty 1 which i create and contains nothing ... i got errors and cant compile it

Comment: I think you mean 'unrecognized' in the title. :)

Comment: @Nadav: I meant the code. Could you please provide a complete cpp file that reproduces the problem. It seems to me to be some error with including. (i guess you wrote a .h file with the class declaration and a .cpp with the method definitions)

Comment: i did post it but it looks like a mess
sorry about it thats the best i can do :S

Comment: could you add a <pre><code> </code></pre> around the code?

Comment: its okey m8 i got it sorted it was all cause i didnt include the "date.h" file where i should have

Comment: If you figured it out and none of the current answers were correct, post an answer yourself that explains the problem and accept it when you can

Comment: @Nadav Stern: I doubt the order of inclusion would be the issue? Are you sure the code you posted and the code you have are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::ofstream`

This is because we have to explicitly specify which ofstream we are talking about. Since the standard namespace `std` contains the name `ofstream`, it has to be explicitly told to the compiler

There are essentially two ways:

Just before all the include files in the .cpp file, have a using directive

1: `using namespace std;`

or

2: prefix each name from the namespace std with `std::`

EDIT 2:

Your revised function declaration should look as follows as Option 1 (from above) is a preferred way to avoid global namespace pollution *usually*

```
void Date::PrintDate(std::ofstream& resultFile) const 
{ 
    resultFile << m_day << "/" << m_month << "/" << m_year; 
}
```

Comment: void Date::PrintDate(std::ofstream& resultFile) or insert the line using namespace std; after the includes (and look up namespaces)

Comment: @Nadav: You can either add a `using namespace std;` right after the `#include` or use the fully qualified name `std::ofstream` every time you use `ofstream`.

Comment: i already am using std namespace and seems like this is not my problem

Comment: @Nadav Stern: `ofstream` is defined inside `std` namespace. Hence you need to take the parameter to `PrintDate` as `std::ofstream& resultFile`.

Comment: @Nadav Stern: Another unrelated comment is to have error/exception handling while dealing with I/O operations

Comment: for some reason after using std:: i am getting this error:
error C2039: 'ofstream' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: this is strange. ofstream should be provided when including <fstream>, and is placed in the std namespace. try either basic_ofstream<char, char_traits<char> > or give us a complete file.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking I was going insane, I tried compiling a modified/simplified version, and it works fine. Are you sure you're using a C++ compiler and not a C compiler? e.g. g++ instead of gcc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void printDate(ofstream& resultFile)
{
resultFile << 1 << "/" << 1 << "/" << 2010;
}

int main(int arg, char **argv)
{
ofstream ofs("ADate.txt");
if (!ofs) cerr << "huh?";
printDate(ofs);
}
```

Comment: i am using visual studio 10 proffesional version and i am using cpp files ofc

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the order of the included "h" files i didnt include in the right order after fixing it all worked perfectly.

Comment: Can you please let us know what exactly it was? What was the old order and what was the new order?